# Transformed config causes "Config Error" to be thrown

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, web-config

I have a ASP.Net MVC application that i am working on. Everything works fine and dandy but as soon as I transform my configs (using ctt.exe), the transformation completes successfully but upon browsing to the application it throws the YSOD with the following message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


 Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: ID1024: The configuration property value is not valid.
Property name: ''
Error: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
```

I can fix this error simply by reformatting the transformed `web.config` using the Visual Studio shortcut (`CTRL+E+D`). During the transformation all the nodes are being clobbered together on the same line. Putting each one of these on individual lines basically fixes the issue. I find this very weird - an XML doc (i would assume) would not care about spaces and newlines as long as there are matching tags. I also went through the process of trying to move the XML elements on a new line one at at time hoping to figure out which one was causing the issue but it really didn't give me any new information. Only that the error message keeps changing.

Has anyone else seen such behavior?

Comment: Does a Debug version not give line numbers of the invalid config file in the YSOD?

Comment: Not an answer, but why not just use the native config transform in Visual Studio? Or SlowCheetah (for non-web projects). My guess is that it could be a bug in ctt.exe. SlowCheetah has a lot more support behind it also.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug with the version of CTT.exe that i had. I upgraded to the newest version and also switched to use `i` flag instead of `pw` and it worked.